# Oracle BETWEEN two dates stored as INT

Tags: sql, oracle, date, int, between

I'm new to DB's, I have a table within Oracle with dates stored as INT, my SELECT statement I include TO_DATE() so I can see the date, I then want to add a WHERE BETWEEN and use "dates" but I feel like there has to be a cleaner more efficient way to do this...I tried using the "alias" for the column but it gives me an error saying it's expecting an integer, that is why I have TO_DATE() again in the WHERE.

```
SELECT to_date('1-Jan-1970 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  + IRF.START_DATE_TIME_KEY/60/60/24) AS START_DATE_TIME_KEY
 WHERE to_date('1-Jan-1970 00:00:00','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  + (IRF.START_DATE_TIME_KEY/60/60/24) 
BETWEEN TO_DATE('20-Feb-2015 00:00:01','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') 
    AND TO_DATE('20-Feb-2015 23:59:59','dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

Comment: Why are you storing dates as numbers? Do you have the ability to make changes to the table (not changing the column, but say _adding_ a column)?

Comment: @DavidFaber without disclosing too much info, it's a vendor app DB, read access only.

Comment: Ugh, a vendor should really know better. That's just lazy.

Comment: I can see storing the Unix timestamp but I can't see a good reason for not storing the date as well. Especially now that one can have virtual columns in Oracle which aren't actually stored on disk but are generated at runtime. Having a virtual column is like having an alias that you can index and use in `WHERE` clauses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple things. One, using `BETWEEN` is not that great for dates because dates aren't exactly discrete. It is better to use something like:

```
WHERE the_date >= TRUNC(start_dt)
  AND the_date < TRUNC(end_dt) + 1;
```

Two, it looks like you're storing the date as the number of seconds that has passed since 1/1/1970? You might be better off at least using ANSI date literals and intervals:

```
SELECT DATE'1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(ifs_start_date_time_key, 'SECOND')
```

You can use an alias for the above, but you can't refer to it in the `WHERE` clause unless you use a subquery. So putting all of this together:

```
SELECT start_date_time_key FROM (
    SELECT DATE'1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(irf.start_date_time_key, 'SECOND') AS start_date_time_key
      FROM mytable irf
) WHERE start_date_time_key >= DATE'2015-02-20'
    AND start_date_time_key < DATE'2015-02-20' + INTERVAL '1' DAY; -- or just DATE'2015-02-20' + 1;
```

---

Someone asked in the comments why not use `BETWEEN` with dates. Well, in this case it almost certainly wouldn't matter because there isn't going to be an index on `start_date_time_key` when it's converted to a `DATE`, but it will matter in cases where there is an index on the `DATE` column, so avoiding `BETWEEN` for dates is just a good habit to get into. I just tried the following on a medium-sized table in my DB:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE TRUNC(date_created) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-1);
```

The above gave me a full table scan with a high CPU cost. Then I did this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE date_created >= TRUNC(SYSDATE-2)
   AND date_created < TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

That gave me a range scan on the index (because there is an index on `date_created`) and a fair CPU cost. I can imagine the contrast would be even greater for a "big" table with millions of rows.

Alternately, one could put a function-based index on the `DATE` column (e.g., `TRUNC(mydate)`), but that won't help you if your date values also have time portions. Just eschew `BETWEEN` -- using `>=` and `<` isn't that much more typing.

---

Another thought just struck me. If the column `IRF.START_DATE_TIME_KEY` is itself indexed, then it might be better to convert the dates to similar integers and use those.

```
SELECT DATE'1970-01-01' + NUMTODSINTERVAL(irf.start_date_time_key, 'SECOND') AS start_date_time_key
  FROM mytable irf
 WHERE irf.start_date_time_key >= (DATE'2015-02-20' - DATE'1970-01-01') * 86400
   AND irf.start_date_time_key < (DATE'2015-02-20' + 1 - DATE'1970-01-01') * 86400
```

It's not pretty, but it would have the advantage of using the index on `IRF.START_DATE_TIME_KEY` in the event there is one.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting to use operators, I will read up on the ANSI funciton suggested.  An d thank you for the sub query suggestion, fantastic content and lots more for me to learn!  Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with dates and between? I think you are referring to the edge case where you want to include 23:59:59 from the day of end_date but not 00:00 from the next day. We can do that with between, `WHERE trunc(the_date) between trunc(start_date) and end_date`

Comment: That would work but might not use the index in the event that `the_date` is indexed. Better to use the column without the `TRUNC()` function.

Comment: I think here you're conflating 2 things that shouldn't be, `WHERE TRUNC(date_created) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)` has no need to be written with the `TRUNC()`, `WHERE date_created BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-2) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-1)` is sufficient, which will perform a range scan or your index. This has nothing to do with the BETWEEN, but is the difference between a sargable and non-sargable predicate.

Comment: The problem with using `BETWEEN` without `TRUNC()` is that you can include an edge condition that you would rather not. You're right that it has nothing to do with the index.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by a view, but since you said the DB is read-only it could be "nested" in your query sort of like this:

```
select REAL_DATE_COL
from
(select *, --code to convert int date to real date-- as REAL_DATE_COL
from MY_TABLE)
where REAL_DATE_COL between date1 and date2
```

This way you only have that ugly conversion code once.

Answer (score 0):

I think using the `date` keyword would make your code much cleaner:

```
SELECT (DATE '1970-01-01' + IRF.START_DATE_TIME_KEY/60/60/24) AS START_DATE_TIME_KEY
FROM . . .
WHERE DATE '1970-01-01' + IRF.START_DATE_TIME_KEY/60/60/24) BETWEEN DATE '2015-02-20' AND '2015-02-20'
```